# Add two different integers together

Tags: c, integer

Currently I am having a speed bump with adding two different integers. For example

```
int i = 32;
int j = 50;
/* Add i and j together into 3250 */
```

What I thought was changing the integers into strings and add them together but that takes too much effort. Is there any other way?

Comment: `int bump = i * 100 + j;`

Comment: This is not "adding" .... and then, is `100*i + j` too obvious or is there something missing to your question?

Comment: Are you saying 3250 is desired result? I guess you need to multiply i by an appropriate factor of 10, if you don't want to convert them to strings.

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/kObq5g)

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the decimal system is:

```
int result = 100* i + j;
```

In case this should be generic you'll need the following algorithm:

```
int shift = 10;
while(j >= shift) {
    pow *= 10;
}
int result = i * pow + j;
```

Comment: I am not in to c but in C# I would convert into string and concat. Is this valid in c?

Comment: @apomene the code would be much more complicated :)

Comment: ok, thanks for the feedback!!

Comment: @apomene there is no string in C - we interpret char array ending with (char)0 as string :)